# Calculate start and end time a batch file took to execute?

Tags: batch-file, time, timer

How can i calculate start and end time using batch script?
I would like my final output only in **minutes**.
For example 1 hours 30 minutes should 90 minutes.

i did find lots of similar questions but not sure how to only calculate the final output in minutes.

```
@echo off

rem Get start time:
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%time%") do (
   set /A "start=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)

rem Any process here...
ECHO Start of Loop
for /L %%n in (1,1,5000) do echo %%n

rem Get end time:
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%time%") do (
   set /A "end=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)

rem Get elapsed time:
REM set /A elapsed=end-start
echo %start%
echo %end%
echo %elapsed%

rem Show elapsed time:
set /A hh=elapsed/(60*60*100), rest=elapsed%%(60*60*100), mm=rest/(60*100), rest%%=60*100, ss=rest/100, cc=rest%%100
set /A mm=elapsed/(60*60*100), rest=elapsed%%(60*60*100), mm=rest/(60*100), rest%%=60*100, ss=rest/100, cc=rest%%100
if %mm% lss 10 set mm=0%mm%
if %ss% lss 10 set ss=0%ss%
if %cc% lss 10 set cc=0%cc%
echo %hh%:%mm% > time.csv
```

Comment: Just multiply %hh% by 60 and add it to %mm% at the very end.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. "set /A hh=elapsed/(60*60*100*60), rest=elapsed%%(60*60*100*60), mm=rest/(60*100), rest%%=60*100, ss=rest/100, cc=rest%%100
if %mm% lss 10 set mm=0%mm%" ?
echo %mm%

Comment: Right before the `echo %hh%:%mm% > time.csv`, add the line `set /a mm=%hh%*60+%mm%` and that will convert hours:minutes into just minutes. Also, change the last line to `echo %%mm% > time.csv` since you don't need hours anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert hours:minutes into just minutes, multiply hours by 60 and then add the minutes.

```
@echo off

rem Get start time:
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%time%") do (
   set /A "start=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)

rem Any process here...
ECHO Start of Loop
for /L %%n in (1,1,5000) do echo %%n

rem Get end time:
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%time%") do (
   set /A "end=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)

rem Get elapsed time:
REM set /A elapsed=end-start
echo %start%
echo %end%
echo %elapsed%

rem Show elapsed time:
set /A hh=elapsed/(60*60*100), rest=elapsed%%(60*60*100), mm=rest/(60*100), rest%%=60*100, ss=rest/100, cc=rest%%100
set /A mm=elapsed/(60*60*100), rest=elapsed%%(60*60*100), mm=rest/(60*100), rest%%=60*100, ss=rest/100, cc=rest%%100
set /a mm=%hh%*60+%mm%
if %mm% lss 10 set mm=0%mm%
echo.>time.csv
echo %mm%>>time.csv
```

I moved the conversion step higher up in case the elapsed time ended in 8 or 9 minutes, since batch considers numbers that start with a 0 to be in octal instead of decimal, and 08 and 09 are not valid octal numbers.

Comment: btw do you know how can  write %mm% value in second line?

Comment: As in keep the first line %hh%:%mm% and then have the larger %mm% value on the next line?

Comment: first line "blank" and second line "minute value" write it to csv file

Comment: A blank line is written in batch by the command `echo.` (note that there is no space between `echo` and `.`) - I have updated my answer.

Comment: Still fail for 08 or 09 hours; what if goes over midnight?

Comment: It won't fail for 08 or 09 hours since at no point in the code is hh set to 0%hh%. As for the timer going past midnight, that's out of scope of this question. He just needed to know how to convert hours to minutes.

Comment: As my short time template is `HH:mm:ss` then `%time%` could display `09:mm:ss` but I'm not sure about in present afternoon time. Then `set /A "start=(((%%a*60)...` would fail. If goes 1 hour past midnight then returns `0-60`; if goes 1 minute past midnight then returns `0-1`. Is it right?